# Insertion of data in mysql with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, blob

I am using Visual Studio 2010 c# to insert huge amount of binary data in mysql database, but when inserting I am getting the following error:

> Exception is+ The connection has been disabled.StackTrace= at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception
>   innerException) at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleErrorNoThrow(OdbcHandle
>   hrHandle, RetCode retcode) at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode) at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod) at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader) at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   UploadFile.btnFileUpload_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\computingClient\UploadFile.aspx.cs:line 133

Mysql datatype is LONGBLOB
Here is my code:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
string sql = "insert into uploadeddata values(?,?,?,?,?)";
//cmd.CommandText = "insert into uploadeddata values(0 ,'" + fileName + "'," + id +",'"+strTokens +"')";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", fileName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerKey", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", strTokens);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", Session["LoggedInUserId"]);
//Logger.writeLog(@"D:\Cloud Computing\CloudClient\Log\Log.txt","id:"+id+",filename:"+fileName+",userid:"+Session["LoggedInUserId"]+",strtokens:"+strTokens);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
progressCounter = 100;
//progress.SecondaryValue = progressCounter;
//progress.SecondaryPercent = progressCounter;
string script = "<script>alert('File uploaded successfully');</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), script, script);
```

Comment: Where are you inserting a binary data?

Comment: What version of MySql, MySql 5 and above support names parameters, you do not need to prefix them with the "@" symbol" like SqlServer. I would also suggest you look at using the Native .Net Connector not ODBC as it is inherintly quicker and offers better TypeConversion semantics. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: @Lloyd Really good comment. Worths to be an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to insert huge amount of data, you should probably increase `max_allowed_packet` in your MySQL configuration file (and restart MySQL, afterwards). This value is usually by default small, to prevent invalid packets sent to mysql, but you can increase it if you expect huge inserts like you do, but note that protocol limit is 1GB (so, no larger packet than that). [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) you can find more info.

Also, as @Lloyd pointed out, you should use .NET Connector instead of odbc driver. In that case, your code should look like this:

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO uploadeddata VALUES (@id, @filename, @serverKey, @token, @userId)";
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("id", 0));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("filename", fileName));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("serverKey", id));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("token", strTokens));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userId", Session["LoggedInUserId"]));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I forgot about the packet size which is a common issue with blobs.